# Circular loop in SetValidator()

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have three entities as follows and they are linked with each other as follows:

```
class Class1 
{ 
   int id { get; set; }
   Class2 { get; set; } 
}

class Class2 
{
   int id { get; set; }
   Class3 { get; set; } 
}

class Class3 
{ 
   int id { get; set; }
   Class1 { get; set; } 
}
```

Now I created validators for each of these class and also have `SetValidator` for the entities linked to them:

```
//Class1 (and other classes) validator has following rules:
public class Class1Validator()
{
    public Class1Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.id).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("id is required.");
        RuleFor(x => x.Class2).SetValidator(new Class2Validator());
    }
}
public class Class2Validator()
{
    public Class2Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.id).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("id is required.");
        RuleFor(x => x.Class3).SetValidator(new Class3Validator());
    }
}
public class Class3Validator()
{
    public Class3Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.id).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("id is required.");
        RuleFor(x => x.Class1).SetValidator(new Class1Validator());
    }
}

//Now when following is called:
var validator = new Class1Validator();
```

When I check validate for `Class1`, it also contains validator for `Class2` and then `Class2` has for `Class3`, and finally at the end `Class3` also has validator for `Class1` which forms an infinite loop and throws the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

and when viewing full details it shows:

> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.

Any solution for this or am I doing something wrong here?

---

Update:
I also tried the below where I can restrict the validator if object is null, but this didnt work:

```
When(x => x.Class1 != null, () => RuleFor(x => x.Class1).SetValidator(new Class1Validator()));
```

Comment: Post the entire definition for your classes. Or, if they are identical, post `Class1` only, but the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to break the circular reference:

- move the `SetValidator` calls out of the constructors, into an `Initialize()` method.
- reuse the validator instances across `SetValidator()` calls. For example, store validator instances as static fields in a static class.

Alright, I'm not that good with words, so here's the code:

The class that hods the validator instances and calls `Initialize()` on them:

```
public static class Validators
{
    public static Class1Validator Class1Validator = new Class1Validator();
    public static Class2Validator Class2Validator = new Class2Validator();
    public static Class3Validator Class3Validator = new Class3Validator();

    static Validators()
    {
        Class1Validator.Initialize();
        Class2Validator.Initialize();
        Class3Validator.Initialize();
    }
}
```

The validators now become:

```
public class Class1Validator : AbstractValidator<Class1>
{
    public Class1Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.id).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("id is required.");
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Class2).SetValidator(Validators.Class2Validator);            
    }
}
public class Class2Validator : AbstractValidator<Class2>
{
    public Class2Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.id).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("id is required.");
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Class3).SetValidator(Validators.Class3Validator);            
    }
}
public class Class3Validator : AbstractValidator<Class3>
{
    public Class3Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.id).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("id is required.");
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Class1).SetValidator(Validators.Class1Validator);            
    }
}
```

I have tested this and it seems to work OK. For example:

```
var validator = Validators.Class1Validator;

var c1 = new Class1
    {
        id = 1,
        Class2 = new Class2
            {
                id = 2,
                Class3 = new Class3
                    {
                        id = 3,
                        Class1 = new Class1
                            {
                                id = 0,
                                Class2 = null
                            }
                    }
            }
    };

var result = validator.Validate(c1);
```

`result` is false here, because the inner `Class1` instance has an `Id` of `0`.

I was worried about the thread safety of this approach, but apparently it's OK, as stated [here](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/77488):

> *The validators are designed to only be instantiated once - they are thread safe.*